# Passing 3D array as parameter to a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, parameters, 3d

Im trying to write a function that sums the elements of a 3d array, however it keeps saying there is a problem with the lines where I pass the 3d array as a parameter. My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum3darray(a[][][], size);

main() {
    int check[3][3][3]={ 0 };
    int size=3;
    printf("The sum is %d\n",sum3darray(check,size));
}

int sum3darray(a[][][],size) {
    int i,j,k,sum=0;
        for(i=0;i<size;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<size;j++) {
                for(k=0;k<size;k++) {
                    printf("i=%d, j=%d,k=%d, checkijk=%d  ",i,j,k,check[i][j][k]);
                    sum+=check[i][j][k];
                    printf("sum=%d\n", sum);
                }
            }
        }
return(sum);
}
```

The compiler flags lines 3 and 11 as problems. Can anyone help?

Comment: It would be great if you attach compiler errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can not omit the types
2. You can omit only the first dimension of an array

---

```
int sum3darray(a[][][], size);
```

should be

```
int sum3darray(int a[][3][3], int size);
```

or

```
int sum3darray(int (*a)[3][3], int size);
```

As pointed out by @CoolGuy, you can omit the name of the parameters in prototypes:

```
int sum3darray(int (*a)[3][3], int size);
```

can be written as

```
int sum3darray(int (*)[3][3], int);
```

Another way to deal with multidimensional arrays (if you don't know the sizes beforehand) is using VLA's (thank you M Oehm) or flattening the array manually, [take a look](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Common_practices).

Comment: I suggest adding "3. You can omit the name of the parameters"

Comment: Possibly useful addendum: As of C99, you can have arguments of variable length when you pass the size before the array: `int sum3darray(int size, int a[size][size][size])`.

Comment: @MOehm: A possibly not so useful addendum: GCC implements forward declaration of parameters as an extension: `int sum3darray(int size; int a[size][size][size], int size);`.