# facing problem while passing a 3 d array to a function

Tags: arrays, c++17

Recently,i was solving a leetcode question which required passing a 3d arrray to function. It appears that i am following all the rules of that,but  it is still showing some error.

Error Message:

```
Line 14: Char 57: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'double (*)[*][*]' with an lvalue of type 'double (*)[n][n]'
             rate+=(solve(n,k-1,r+dir[i][0],c+dir[i][1],dp)*0.125);
                                                        ^~
Line 5: Char 53: note: passing argument to parameter 'dp' here
        double solve(int n,int k,int r,int c,double dp[][n][n]){
                                                    ^
```

Code:

```
class Solution {
public:
        int dir[8][2]={{-2,-1},{-2,1},{-1,-2},{-1,2},{2,-1},{2,1},{1,2},{1,-2}};

        double solve(int n,int k,int r,int c,double dp[][n][n]){
        if(r<0 || r>=n || c<0 || c>=n)
            return 0;
        if(k==0)
            return 1.0;
        if(dp[k][r][c]!=-1)
            return dp[k][r][c];
        double rate=0;
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
             rate+=(solve(n,k-1,r+dir[i][0],c+dir[i][1],dp)*0.125);
        }
        return dp[k][r][c]= rate;
    }
    double knightProbability(int n, int k, int row, int column) {
        double dp[k+1][n][n];
        memset(dp,-1.0,sizeof(dp));
        return solve(n,k,row,column,dp);
    }

};
```

Links of articles to I have referred to solve this problem before posting here:-

[article on stack oveflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29605133/passing-3d-array-as-parameter-to-a-function-in-c)

[article on multi dimensional arrays.](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2019/03/27/c-programming-passing-multi-dimensional-array-to-function/)

Comment: Use `std::array` not C-style arrays.

Comment: why was i not facing this kind of problem till now if that's the issue? i use 2d arrays and pass them in the same way i showed above.

Comment: That's not an issue, but simply idiomatic C++ code.

Comment: You are trying to use [variable-length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)(VLA). These are a feature of C language, they don't exist in standard C++, though some compilers accept them as an extension. Even those that do, appear to have trouble with multidimensional VLA. [This compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/PPavqb67K) but [this doesn't](https://godbolt.org/z/xz43x9ofn)

Comment: @infinitezero `std::array` ain't gonna fly here; the size is only known at runtime.

Comment: @Igor then the obvious choice is std::vector

Comment: @IgorTandetnik so does that mean even if i write a code like this: ```int n; cin>>n ; int arr[n] ``` ,is  it invalid in c by standards? because when i try to compile it,it gives me correct output

Comment: It's valid in C, but not in C++. Like I said, some C++ compilers allow it as an extension. I'm not familiar with VLA myself, I don't know how to help you make the current approach work (on those compilers that allow them).